# Solana's Pubkeys are of which representation of Curve25519?

Tags: solana-program

I wanted to know this: Are solana pubkeys EdwardsPoint or Montgomery representation of curve25519?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [solana glossary](https://docs.solana.com/terminology#account) writes

> The key may be one of:
>
> - an ed25519 public key
> - a program-derived account address (32byte value forced off the ed25519 curve)
> - a hash of an ed25519 public key with a 32 character string

Or, to directly answer your question: Solana pubkeys use points on the **Edwards representation** of Curve25519 in the first case of the above definition.